# Changing background color of table row according to clicks

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have a table layout with table rows building according to data given by JSON. I want to highlight a row after pressing it but I need that only one row to be highlighted in every given time, it means that if I highlight a row and then press another row the last row should be highlighted and the first row should not. Everything is working fine but I can't get a row to not be highlighted after it became highlighted. This is my code:

```
TableLayout tv = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tblFrnd);
tv.removeAllViewsInLayout();
int flag = 1;

for (int i = -1; i < ans.length(); i++) {
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(AddFriend.this);

    tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    if (flag == 1) {
        TextView b3 = new TextView(AddFriend.this);
        b3.setText("Display Name");
        b3.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        b3.setTextSize(20);
        b3.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
        tr.addView(b3);

        TextView b4 = new TextView(AddFriend.this);
        b4.setPadding(50, 0, 0, 0);
        b4.setTextSize(20);
        b4.setText("User Name");
        b4.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        tr.addView(b4);

        TextView b5 = new TextView(AddFriend.this);
        b5.setPadding(90, 0, 0, 0);
        b5.setTextSize(20);
        b5.setText("ID");
        b5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        b5.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        tr.addView(b5);

        tv.addView(tr);

        final View vline = new View(AddFriend.this);
        vline.setLayoutParams(new
                TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 2));
        vline.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        tv.addView(vline);
        flag = 0;

    } else {

        JSONObject json_data = ans.getJSONObject(i);

        TextView b = new TextView(AddFriend.this);
        String str = json_data.getString("DisplayName");
        b.setText(str);
        b.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
        b.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        b.setTextSize(15);

        tr.addView(b);

        TextView b1 = new TextView(AddFriend.this);
        b1.setPadding(50, 0, 0, 0);
        b1.setTextSize(15);
        String str1 = json_data.getString("UserName");
        b1.setText(str1);
        b1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        tr.addView(b1);

        final TextView b2 = new TextView(AddFriend.this);
        b2.setPadding(90, 0, 0, 0);
        b2.setTextSize(15);
        String str2 = String.valueOf(json_data.getInt("UserID"));
        b2.setText(str2);
        b2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        b2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        tr.addView(b2);

        tr.setClickable(true);
        tr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Yellow));
            }
        });

        tv.addView(tr);

        final View vline1 = new View(AddFriend.this);
        vline1.setLayoutParams(new
                TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1));
        vline1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        tv.addView(vline1);
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The code and the question do not seem to correlate....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Take `int selectedRow = -1` in class.
- Add a function in the class:

  ```
  private void updateHighlightedRow()
  {
      // loop through the rows and set the background
      // for a row to highlighted color if the row index == selectedRow 
      // else sent normal bg color
  }
  ```
- While adding row, make the row clickable and in click listener set row index to `selectedRow`, then call `updateHighlightedRow`

This should do the things.

Comment: How can I loop through the rows to set their background? what to write in the for function?

Comment: Loop using `getChildCount` and `getChildAt` methods of `TableLayout` object

Answer (score 0):

make the textview setClickable(false).